# Rearranging data frame columns in R (mutate, dplyr)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame like so

```
Type  Number  Species
A     1         G    
A     2         R 
A     7         Q
A     4         L
B     4         S
B     5         T
B     3         H
B     9         P
C     12        K
C     11        T
C     6         U
C     5         Q
```

Where I have used group_by(Type)
My goal is to collapse this data by having NUMBER be the top 2 values in the number column, and then making a new column(Number_2) that is the second 2 values.
Also I would want the Species values for the bottom two numbers to be deleted, so that the species corresponds to the higher number in the row
I would like to use dplyr and the final would look like this

```
Type  Number Number_2   Species       
A     7    1               Q
A     4    2               L 
B     5    3               T
B     9    4               P
C     12   6               K
C     11   5               T
```

as of now the order that number_2 is in doesn't matter, as long as it is in the same type.... 
I don't know if this is possible but if it is does anyone know how...

thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant change the data on my own, not on this question!

Answer (score 7):

You can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(-Number), list(Number1=Number[1:2], 
                                Number2=Number[3:4],
                                Species=Species[1:2]), keyby = Type]
 #   Type Number1 Number2 Species
 #1:    A       7       2       Q
 #2:    A       4       1       L
 #3:    B       9       4       P
 #4:    B       5       3       T
 #5:    C      12       6       K
 #6:    C      11       5       T
```

Or using `dplyr` with `do`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
   group_by(Type) %>%
   arrange(desc(Number)) %>%
   do(data.frame(Type=.$Type[1L],
                Number1=.$Number[1:2], 
                Number2 = .$Number[3:4],
                Species=.$Species[1:2], stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
 #   Type Number1 Number2 Species
 #1    A       7       2       Q
 #2    A       4       1       L
 #3    B       9       4       P
 #4    B       5       3       T
 #5    C      12       6       K
 #6    C      11       5       T
```

Comment: I added an edit to my post, could you possibly take another look at it -- Thanks!

Comment: I was in the middle of posting the same thing as I don't think this can be done simply with `dplyr`. As a side note, you don't need `[order(Type)]`, just use `keyby` instead of `by`

Comment: thanks! i don't need to necessarily use dplyr so that is ok

Comment: @DavidArenburg I posted a solution with `dplyr`.  You are right.  It's a bit too complicated.

Comment: Seems like it should be possible to create a `c(1,1,2,2)` variable and then `dcast`, but I don't have the skills or tools. Saw something like this on Arun's new slides (search for "dcast"): https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/talks/ArunSrinivasanUseR2015.pdf `do` from dplyr always seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @Frank I was also thinking about `dcast` for the first version of the question but with the new version it will be harder because you don't need all the values in `Species`

Comment: Great answer! This is what we mean by *straightforward* :-).  You may want to use `(.N-1):.N` (or use `tail()`) instead of hard-coding as 3:4, but that's minor.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different dplyr approach.

```
library(dplyr)

# Start creating the data set with top 2 values and store as df1:
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>%
  top_n(2, Number) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Type, Number)

# Then, get the anti-joined data (the not top 2 values), arrange, rename and select
# the number colummn and cbind to df1:
out <- df %>%
  anti_join(df1, c("Type","Number")) %>%
  arrange(Type, Number) %>%
  select(Number2 = Number) %>%
  cbind(df1, .)
```

This results in:

```
> out
#  Type Number Species Number2
#1    A      4       L       1
#2    A      7       Q       2
#3    B      5       T       3
#4    B      9       P       4
#5    C     11       T       5
#6    C     12       K       6
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be another option using `ddply`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat[order(Number)], .(Type), summarize, 
      Number1 = Number[4:3],  Number2 = Number[2:1], Species = Species[4:3])

#  Type Number1 Number2 Species
#1    A       7       2       Q
#2    A       4       1       L
#3    B       9       4       P
#4    B       5       3       T
#5    C      12       6       K
#6    C      11       5       T
```